# Krita works, but no (python) plugins

Tags: linux, plugins, krita

I'm trying to install some Krita plugins and they are Python based.
My Krita version is 5.1.3 (this is newer than the minimal 5.0 for python plugins) and I have Python3 installed already.

The menu option `Tools->Scripts` is empty, there should be at-least a "Import Python Plugin" option.

Also the `Setting->Configure Krita...->Python Plugin Manager` is empty, there should be some plugins by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install or see if `python-pyqt5` package is installed.

For Arch linux: `sudo pacman -S python-pyqt5`

This solved atleast the plugin menu's, the few default plugins showed up and the manager was able to import new plugins for me.